# Can you remove sort and filter options in TableSorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is it possible to remove, disable, hide sorting & filter options for Column 0 in Tablesorter 2.27.6?

The column has an images and wont need the above features. Ive tried hiding but this just moves the column headers to the left & out of alignment (the furtherst right column no longer has a header)

Thanks in advance

Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to add these class names to the first column:

```
<th class="sorter-false filter-false"></th>
```

This disables but doesn't hide the filter, so you'll need the following css:

```
.tablesorter-filter.disabled { display: none; }
```

Ref:

- [Disable sort](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html).
- [Disable filter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#classes).